# Deep learning network for classification

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification, deep-learning

I know this is a generic question but I would like some feedback.
So, I have an image classification task, which I am trying to solve with neural networks. I already have my feature vectors.
There are 3 salient feature vectors (point coordinates in 2d space), each of which can belong to three classes.
These classes are not the same among these 3 features. (for instance, one could be "up down straight" the other "round square triangular").
These are combined in an overall classification task in 6 output classes (not 27 as the number of combinations would maybe imply).
So, what's the question: 
Are deep learning networks / convolutional networks a good solution to this? Or would you prefer something else? (I have just began learning about these and cant make up my mind yet, so I would appreciate some feedback from more experienced users)

Comment: Probably not, since you have low dimensional existing features. Techniques like CNNs, or (stacked) autoencoders shine when it comes to learning features from unlabeled data. Stanford has some good [tutorials](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial).

Comment: thanks a lot for your response :D I ll look into them.

Comment: There is a Matlab toolbox for Deep Learning in github: https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, your problem is not so complicated to implement deep learning. Because you have low dimensional features and few class outputs. Deep learning is mostly for highly nonlinear and large-size classification problems. I suggest you you to use AdaBoost or SVM classifier for this kind of simple classification tasks. Matlab has great tools for above techniques.